How renaming a proto field can be a breaking change during the rolling deployment?
I have several Golang microservices communicating with each other via gRPC, using protocol buffers (proto) to define the APIs. The proto file is centralized and shared across multiple services.
Is there a case when renaming a proto field, without altering its type or index, considered a breaking change during a rolling update?

Renaming a field shouldn't affect on-the-wire messages as long -- to your point -- that the type and tag are unchanged. However, code that's bound to code generated by protoc will break as the code uses the field name and e.g. JSON serialization will change (for the same reason). It's unclear what you mean by "rolling update" as I would assume the update is replicating the same binary and this should either work or not.

In pb encoding, the key only uses the index and does not need the name. refer https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/#cheat-sheet-key
